# No sound when playing mp3/midi from any device except Nord Piano

Tags: midi, cubase

I recorded a midi file in Cubase11 Elements 11 using Nord Piano 4. I exported the audio both in midi and mp3 but there's no sound. I can hear my track only when playing directly from Cubase when connected to my Nord Piano. Also I can open midi from GarageBand but it opens it up with its own sound from its local library. What I want - to have a recording with the original Nord sound when playing from any device.

Comment: If you are mainly interested in the Nord sound, why not record the sound instead of a midi track?

Comment: I'm surprised the MP3 doesn't export with the soundfont. However, I believe this is normal behaviour for MIDIs - the proliferation of videos with various computers' interpretation of music from games from *The Incredible Machine* series is one attestation to this.

Comment: If you have recorded midi in cubase, but recorded no audio, "no sound" is exactly what I'd expect, i think? Have you actually recorded any audio in cubase before you export? You should be able to record the output of the Nord playing the midi track...

Comment: @Tom I wanted to clean up some things like a dirty pedal or occasionally loud sound where it should be quiet, and midi allows you to do all of it

Comment: @topomorto I'm very new to this so my question might sound silly, but do you mean that I can play midi through the Nord Piano and make it get recorded as audio?

Comment: @DariaIvanova yes - MIDI is not audio, it's just instructions to the instrument saying 'play this note', 'stop playing this note', etc. If you want to get an audio recording, you'll need to record the audio output of the nord while you are sending the midi instructions in to it. The workflow you suggest - record midi, clean up a few mistakes in the midi, then replay the fixed midi and record the audio - sounds very sensible.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood what you want to do, the workflow should be the following:

1. Record MIDI (you have done it)
2. Edit the MIDI recording, as needed
3. Create an audio track in your DAW.
4. Connect output of your electric piano to the input of your audio interface.
5. Record Audio: set the cursor to the beginning of the project (or beginning of the section you want to record) and click "record". Let the whole piece play until the end, then click "stop".

Note, that as audio will be transmitted in analog domain you need to take some steps to ensure good sound quality, the same as with recording real instruments:

- make sure there are no drops in recording: set audio interface buffers/latency sufficiently high, don't load your computer with other unnecessary tasks at the same time
- set the gain correctly: typically you want to set your piano volume to the maximum and adjust the audio interface gain so that the signal is high, but doesn't reach the maximum even in the loudest parts
- make sure the audio cables and connectors are in good shape, avoid touching them during the recording

Comment: Thank you! My mistake was that for some reason when I tried to record audio I thought that I don't have to turn on the sound on the Piano at all. Thought the sound will transfer digitally (that's how far I'm from sound production). Now everything makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DariaIvanova Your assumption wasn't completely unfounded, USB is often used to transfer audio, but in case of your particular piano only MIDI is transmitted.